# Storing geometries as SDO_POINT_TYPE with Hibernate 5 and Oracle

Tags: hibernate-5.x, jts, hibernate-spatial

I am using `Hibernate 5.1.0.Final` in a Java application for database persistence. That will be handy for us as we expect to hit Oracle and Postgres instances, so we can have this ORM as an abstraction layer.
In a [former issue when querying geometries using Hibernate-spatial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861793/hibernate-5-hql-translator-for-oracle-spatial) I posted some of my configuration.
The problem now is when we persist some geometry fields in Oracle. In my POJO I have an import :

`import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;`

So that I define the following attribute in my class :

```
@Column(name = "geom")
protected Geometry geom;
```

It gets persisted and I can use predicates to query it. But looking inside the database I can see the content of the geom field is :

`MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,4326,NULL,MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1,1),MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(0.094,51.488))`

Instead of what I would like, which is faster to query and is recommended by Oracle :

`MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,4326,MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(0.094,51.488,NULL),NULL,NULL)`

What should I do in order to store this as a point (`SDO_POINT_TYPE`) and not as an array (`SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY`) ?

EDIT : I tried changing to `Point` as shown below, but it didn't make a difference, as far as I can tell.

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
(...)
@Column(name = "geom")
protected Point geom;
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that currently there is no way to force Hibernate to store points as points instead of an array of coordinates. I went deeper into this and I came out with a tweak to the source code mostly for me, but also for those who need to do so.

I created a pull request to the original project. Even though it may or may not be considered for the master, anybody can potentially create their own customized version of `OracleJDBCTypeFactory.java` taking it from here :

https://github.com/GeoLatte/geolatte-geom/pull/42

Update : This was merged into master. It should be ready for next release of `geolate-geom`. As per @maesenka 's comment :

> You must set a system property `GEOLATTE_USE_SDO_POINT_TYPE=true` to enable this feature.